# Vue js get checked value of checkbox from multiple checkbox

Tags: vuejs2

How will get checkbox target checked value from multiple checkbox inside loop

This is my code

```
<div v-for="(video, videoIndex) in videos" :key="videoIndex" class="col-3">
   <div class="col-12 mb-3 p-0">
        <div class="row">
            <b-form-checkbox
                switch 
                   :id="'video-'+video.id"
                   :value="video.id"
                   v-model="checked"
                   @input="checkboxVal"
                   unchecked-value="not_accepted"
                   >
                   </b-form-checkbox>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

when i click on a checkbox i need to get current checkbox value from multiple checkbox.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the property of `v-model`, `checked`, should be an array.

Comment: yes v-model checked is an array and method checkboxVal is working for all the id in checked array, when click on a single checkbox. can't target current clicked checkbox.

Comment: Vue's official docs have an example of what you are trying to achive. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox